# PDO from hosting to SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, odbc

I have a hosting with cPanel and a Windows VPS with SQL Server. I'm trying to do a PDO connection to SQL Server but I keep getting this error:

> The Following error has occurred:SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: This extension
> requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server to communicate with
> SQL Server. Access the following URL to download the ODBC Driver for
> SQL Server for x64: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712

I am a little bit confused am I supposed to install driver in Windows VPS or it is a hosting issue?

This is my simple PHP code:

```
try {
    $con = new PDO('sqlsrv:Server=IPADDRESS;Database=DBNAME', 'sa', 'PASSWORD'); 
    $handler->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo "The Following error has occurred:".$e->getMessage()."";
```

Btw sqlsrv, pdo_sqlsrv and odbc are enabled in Hosting.
Help please

Comment: You need to have the ODBC driver installed on the machine that is running your PHP code (the database client). It is not necessary to have the ODBC driver installed on the database server.

Comment: Do you mean I have to have ODBC driver installed in Hosting? I have it checked on my Hosting. Maybe I'll have to contact them.

Answer (score 0):

You must install the driver in Windows, so follow the instructions on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/install-the-sql-server-driver-for-php